# Neo4j: How to have '|' as delimeter when export data in csv?

Tags: jquery, neo4j, export, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am using the following query to save my data as csv file on my Desktpo:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a) RETURN a", 
 'C:/Users/Raf/Desktop/results.csv', {});
```

This query returns me a csv where the data are in quotes and the delimeter is a comma ','.

I would like to not have the data in the quotes and have the '|' pipe as a delimiter, how could I do?

Comment: I think that's not supported yet (custom delims) but different types of quoting is supported. Please raise a GH issue.

Comment: Yes custom delims is supported, @Raj found the solution, the quotes are an open point yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass delimiter in a parameter with key **"d"**.

**Ex:**

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a) RETURN a",
'C:/Users/Raf/Desktop/results.csv', {d: '|'});
```

Comment: Thank you in this way the comma there isn't anymore, but why I have all data in quotes???

Comment: it should be {delim:'|'} insted of {d:'|'}